# Calculate the median benefit for this policy

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

An insurance policy reimburses dental expense, $X$, up to a maximum benefit of $250$. The probability density function for $X$ is:

$f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
       ce^{-0.004x}, & x \ge 0 \\
        0, & otherwise \\
     \end{array}
   \right.$

where $c \in \mathbb{R}$

Calculate the median benefit for this policy.

**My attempt**

Let $Y$=insurance benefit. Then $Y=min\{x,250\}$.

Want: $\pi_{0.5}$ s.t. $0.5=\int_{0}^{\pi_{0.5}}f(x)dx=F(\pi_{0.5})$

$1=\int_{0}^{\infty}ce^{-0.004x}dx \Rightarrow c=\frac{1}{250}$. Thus, $f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
       \frac{e^\frac{-x}{250}}{250}, & x \ge 0 \\
        0, & otherwise \\
     \end{array}
   \right.$

As $X \sim Exp(\frac{1}{250})$, then $F(x)=P(X<x)=1-e^{-\frac{x}{250}},x \ge 0$.

$F(\pi_{0.5}):=0.5 \leftrightarrow 1-e^{-\frac{\pi_{0.5}}{250}}=0.5 \Rightarrow \pi_{0.5}=-250ln(0.5) \approx 173.29$.

I know that $y=x$ if $x<250$, so in this case, the median benefit = the median dental expense because $173.29 < 250?$ But what happens when $x \ge 250$; that is, $F(\pi_{0.9}):=0.9 \Rightarrow \pi_{0.9} \approx 575.65$? My understanding is that $\pi_{0.9}=575.65$ means the area under $f(x)$ to the left of $575.65$ is $0.9$, but since $575.65>250$ we have that the 90th percentile of the benefit for this policy=maximum benefit for this policy=250?

Answer (score 1):

Your CDF of $Y$ is

$$F_Y(y)=(1-e^{-y/250})\cdot \mathbb{1}_{[0;250)}(y)+\mathbb{1}_{[250;+\infty)}(y)$$

and the median is the value where

$$\text{me}=F^{-1}(0.5)$$

observing that $F(250)=0.6321$ this means that the median is in the interval $[0;250)$ and it can be derived inverting $F$

that is

$$y=250\cdot \log 2\approx173.29$$